# how do I assign an expression with free type variables, like I assign other functions f as val x = f :?

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

how do I assign an expression with free type variables, like I assign other functions f as val x =  f : ??

I have

```
 fun curry f  x  y = f (x,y);
 val dummy = fn (x,y) => {a=x,b=y}  (* or anything with free type *)
 val dummCd = fn x=> fn y=> {a=x,b=y}
```

I thought that 'curry dummy' would  work like 'dummCd', but,

```
 dummCd
 val it = fn: 'a -> 'b -> {a: 'a, b: 'b}
```

and

```
 curry dummy:
 stdIn:13.1-13.8 Warning: type vars not generalized because of
   value restriction are instantiated to dummy types (X1,X2,...)
 val it = fn : ?.X1 -> ?.X2 -> {a:?.X1, b:?.X2}
```

So this becomes useless when assigned.
I can do this:

```
 fun x a b =curry dummy a b ;
```

but this is a bit clumsy. When I put what I do here, into a function

```
 val a = fn tr => (fn a=> fn b=> tr a b)
 val x = a (curry dummy)
 val x = fn : ?.X1 -> ?.X2 -> {a:?.X1, b:?.X2}
```

I get the same problem back.
How can I assign 'curry dummy' without using the extra a and b ? I mean like

```
 val x =  a ( curry dummy )
```

where a might be a function, and x behaves like dummCd

Thanks for tips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, you cannot do what you want.

In Standard ML '97, a value declaration can only bind a type variable if the right-hand side of the binding is a "non-expansive" expression, meaning that it conforms to a very restrictive subset of the expression syntax that doesn't make it possible to generate any new ref cells or exception names. Since this is a *syntactic* check, it doesn't take into account the definition of `curry` at all; *you* know that `curry` doesn't create any ref cells or exception names (and that `val dummCd = curry dummy` would therefore be safe), but all the compiler sees at this point is that `curry dummy` calls a function that *could* do those things.

So if you want `dummCd` to be called with arbitrary types (meaning, you want it to have the non-trivial type scheme ∀αβ.α→β→{a:α,b:β} with bound type variables), then you'll need to declare it using e.g. `val dummCd = fn ...` or `fun dummCd ...`; you can't just write `val dummCd = ...` with whatever you want on the right-hand side.

Standard ML '90 was a bit more permissive in this respect — it encoded the relevant information about the behavior of `curry` into the type system (by marking a type variable as "imperative", e.g. `'_a` rather than `'a`, if it was involved in the types of any ref cells or exception names), and used that type information to decide whether `val dummCd = curry dummy` should be allowed to bind its type variables — but that system was deemed too messy and complicated, especially since it forced implementation details into signatures, so it was scrapped in Standard ML '97 and replaced with the current syntax-only system where all type variables are presumed imperative.

Comment: Very clear thanks. I see that I could have reduced the example more to `val y = (fn x=>x)` and `val y = (fn x=>x)(fn x=>x)`, and in the second case I must constrain the type

Comment: @jordyTTx: You're welcome! . . . except that I've just realized that my explanation isn't 100% correct, in that something like `val dummCd = curry dummy` could bind a type variable if `curry` were a constructor; for example, `val someOfNil : 'a list option = SOME nil` is fine. That's not a strictly syntactic check, since identifier status is part of the static semantics, rather than the syntax. But for your purposes, since `curry` *isn't* a constructor, it amounts to the same thing.